# Javascript filter for multidimensional json object

Tags: javascript, json, object, filter, filtering

Can't use javascript filter in multi-dimensional object.

```js
var object = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "General",
  "cards": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "shawn"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "neo"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "CEO",
  "cards": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Raman"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sheena"
  }]
}]

function searchFor(item) {
  return item.cards.filter(
    (card) => {
      return card.name.indexOf("Raman") !== -1;
    }
  );
}

var filtered = object.filter(searchFor);

console.log(filtered);
```

This is how I am trying, inside the searchFor card.name I am getting the correct card name but filtering is returning all the cards.Its not filtering.

Could any help me with this.

Comment: An empty array isn't falsey in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were returning the filtered array, which would produce a `TRUE` result whenever `cards` existed. So you can just turn that into a boolean, by saying when the `item.cards.filter(...).length > 0`.

```js
var object = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "General",
  "cards": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "shawn"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "neo"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "CEO",
  "cards": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Raman"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sheena"
  }]
}]

var searchFor = (card) => card.name.indexOf("Raman") > -1;
var filteredCards = object.reduce((cards, item) => cards.concat(item.cards.filter(searchFor)), []);
var filteredObj = object.map(i => {
  i.cards = i.cards.filter(searchFor);
  return i;
}).filter(i => i.cards.length)

console.log(filteredCards, filteredObj)
```

**Updated**

I updated the code snippet to produce either the cards which were found. I also provide a method for returning all objects which contain the needed cards, and filter out the other cards.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but Sheena card is also returning.I need only Raman.

Comment: @BalajiChandrasekaran, I think I understand what you are asking for now. I updated my answer to extract only the cards with the "Raman" name. Is this more what you were wanting?

Comment: It works and, I understand the code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

An empty array isn't considered falsey in Javascript. So instead of returning the result of filtering the `cards` array, test its length.

```js
var object = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "General",
  "cards": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "shawn"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "neo"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "CEO",
  "cards": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Raman"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sheena"
  }]
}]

function searchFor(item) {
  return item.cards.filter(
    (card) => {
      return card.name.indexOf("Raman") !== -1;
    }
  ).length != 0;
}

var filtered = object.filter(searchFor);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I need to filter the cards only, but here it's shorting the main array. I need both the general,ceo array. Inside cards should be filtered by name.In this example I need Raman card alone and it should remove Sheena card

Comment: Hi, I need to remove Sheena , which is also return in this code.

Comment: If you only wanted to filter the cards, why did you write `object.filter()`?

Comment: You should edit the question to make it clearer what you're trying to do. Explain that you only want to filter cards, not the outer `object` array. Show the desired result.

Comment: Sure thank you for your effort, I will make sure I specify my desired result next time. Based on the example of a javascript filter, I used filter even for multi-dimensional object.Thank you very much.

Comment: The point is that you should only use `filter` if you're trying to get a subset of that array. If you want to keep the entire first dimension, and filter the second dimension, you don't filter the first dimension.

Comment: You should edit this question, not just keep it in mind for next time, so that future readers of this question will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

**// HTML Part**

```
  <div class="filter-list">
    <button class="filter" data-filter-key="all">all</button>
    <button class="filter" data-filter-key="open">open</button>
    <button class="filter" data-filter-key="done">done</button>
  </div>
```

**// CSS Part**

```
.filter:hover,
.filter:focus,
[data-active-filter="all"] .filter[data-filter-key="all"],
[data-active-filter="done"] .filter[data-filter-key="done"],
[data-active-filter="open"] .filter[data-filter-key="open"] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

[data-active-filter="open"] [data-completed="true"],
[data-active-filter="done"] [data-completed="false"] {
  display: none;
}
```

**// Script Part**

```
(function () {
  const mainNode = document.querySelector("main");
  const filters = document.querySelector(".filter-list");

  for (const filter of filters.children) {
    filter.addEventListener("click", () => {
      mainNode.setAttribute(
        "data-active-filter",
        filter.getAttribute("data-filter-key")
      );
    });
  }

  mainNode.setAttribute("data-active-filter", "all");
})();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer, but can you also add some explanation on how your code solves the problem?